# BigQuery data transfer service for Search Ads 360: Permission bigquery.datasets.get denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-iam

We have scheduled a daily [BigQuery Data Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/sa360-transfer) for copying the Search Ads 360 into our dataset `google_search_ads_360`.  For the account created the data transfer service the [required permission](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/sa360-transfer#required_permissions) were given:

- `roles/bigquery.dataOwner` for `google_search_ads_360`
- `rolesserviceusage.serviceUsageConsumer` for the project

The initial load was successful but the last runs are failing for all tables with the following error:

```
    Failed to start job for table p_AdvertiserDeviceStats_ID$ID with error PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission bigquery.datasets.get denied on dataset PROJECT_NUMBER:google_search_ads_360 (or it may not exist).
```

Does anyone know which for which account the permissions are missing?

Comment: 1.) Just to clarify, what you did on your dataset `google_search_ads_360` is assign `roles/bigquery.dataOwner` for the created account at dataset level only? 2.) Is `rolesserviceusage.serviceUsageConsumer` the only role assigned on IAM for your account on data transfer service? If not, can you provide the other roles as well?

Comment: For the created account I have roles/bigquery.dataOwner on the dataset google_search_ads_360 and roles/bigquery.admin in general as well for creating the DTS. For roles/bigquery.jobUser as well and a lot of other roles for different services (CloudStorage, CloudSQL, AI Notebooks, ...)

Comment: On IAM & Admin, can you try to change the roles to "Editor" of the person creating the transfer config? Is the created account a email address or a service account? Just to identify if the permission error is on the project level or the dataset level.

Comment: The used account is my personal one but unfortunately I cannot grant "Editor" roles to it due to our company policies

Comment: I see. It might be better to contact [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub#section-2) if you have an existing support package or free trial credits so they can properly check the setup of the permissions.

Comment: I do - thanks for helping so far